# Android App on iPhone / iPad?

Tags: android, iphone, ipad

I wrote an Android App. When you start the android app you see a Web browser that loads a Website. That's it. Is that now possible to start this app on iPhone or iPad? On some websites, some people are saying it works, but i don't see any tutorials or examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to show the webview then you can use UIWebView as Morad has suggested thats easiest. Other alternative for handling such applications on multiple platforms is by using [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) or  [appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/) .

Answer (score 1):

It will work , if you write the code in obj-c in your i products. Android uses java , which is a different language.  Please show what you have tried.

Comment: No, you can't have this app for iOS. It is vaporware, and would be rejected from the AppStore faster than you can say 'oops'.

Comment: not sure why -1, question was not to post it at store. was if it can run or not.

Comment: -1, because it doesn't help the OP if it just runs, if it cannot get to the AppStore. This is a misleading answer.

Comment: read the question please. it states "start this app on" never stated he will post this in store. Maybe hes doing this for learning purposes, you can't assume every app made will be posted in an app store.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple to create an app that loads a website, just put a UIWebView and load the url. The problem is that if you want to release the app on AppStore you're going against the AppStore restrictions.

> 2.12 Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may
>   be rejected

Take a look at this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421002/app-rejected-from-apple-app-store-because-uiwebview-need-some-advice) thread.