# What is the easiest way to turn a webapp into a mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

The company I work for is exploring creating "an app" version of their online video delivery webapp. The webapp is HTML5 and streams video. Nothing too scary but a lot of the stuff is server-side authentication with third party video hosts, code that will never be in a mobile app for security reasons.

The webapp has a lovely mobile stylesheet that works fine. We want an app that:

- Shows a quick splash screen (and even that's optional)
- Load the existing mobile website (not include it within the app)

And have the ability to specify an icon, give it a name and then shove it in the relevant marketplaces. That should satisfy the marketing department and it means I stay in control of what the app actually does.

Yeah, it's possibly the laziest app development ever... But, **what's the simplest way to generate something like this?** I was imagining there might be something out there already where you feed it your starting URL, splash screen, icon and name and it hands you back a multi-platform app.

Note: I'm not looking for something to create an app that looks like the mobile website and I'm not looking to put the content of the mobile website inside the app, I essentially just want a browser that loads the real mobile site.

Comment: I wish the downvoters would explain what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: I hope you're aware that Apple doesn't allow apps that do nothing apart from loading a website. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421002/app-rejected-from-apple-app-store-because-uiwebview-need-some-advice

Comment: Thanks for that @Mar0ux - I'll pass that up the foodchain.

Comment: Its a risk that they'll reject the wrapped web-app, but I've seen enough examples of apps on the app store that are obviously just a web view to know they aren't as diligent as one might expect at rejecting them.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://www.shoutem.com/. They provide a service similar to what you seem to be looking for but they charge royally for it. Considering the extra features you can easily add with their service your marketing department might just smell profit from using it and may therefore happily sign it off with their well known satanic smile.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of websites which provide easy web app development for a website. One of the famous is [App Maker](http://mobile.conduit.com/) . Others include:http://www.viziapps.com/ and http://ibuildapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

Since posting this, I have found:

- http://www.websitetoapp.net/create

Feed it a URL and an Icon and it'll give you an Android app. Pay $5 and they'll disable adverts. Seems like it might be perfect for the Android half of this project.

Now, is there anything out there that will do this for other platforms?